# When to use HandlerThread and when to set new Looper

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I'm learning Android, and I have few problems understanding `Threads-Handlers`.

I saw examples where you declare a handler in working Thread that works with `Looper` of `mainThread`- it's clear to me.

Also I saw examples where you create a working `Thread` and declare your own `Looper`, like this:

```
public void run() {

    Looper.prepare();
    handler = new Handler();
    Looper.loop(); 
}
```

I understand it creates a thread with with own `Looper` and a private message queue but what is the purpose of this and why use it?
Is it a message queue that can work on the application UI like `mainThread` can? is it a speed issue of working on UI faster then `mainThread`?

And one more thing...I saw a class `HandlerThread`, if I understand it right, It's the same as creating a new Thread and setting to it new `Looper` like I showed in the example above? If not I'm interested to know what is the difference and where to use it?

Comment: i guess you have been looking at the code for `IntentService`?

Comment: @njzk2 There's plenty of other reasons to want a message handler in a separate thread.

Comment: @njzk2 No, I saw it in many examples without `IntentService`

Comment: @AlexKulr: because IntentService is a typical example of the use of a HandlerThread and a Looper. It serves to make sure there is only one thread that executes the task, and allows to queue tasks to the thread. I am not certain why this approach was taken rather than an ExecutorService with a single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be plenty of reasons why to do that.  For example, if processing a message takes a significant amount of time you may want to do it on another thread to prevent the UI thread from freezing.  It wouldn't be able to directly manipulate the UI thread, but you could always do a runOnUiThread to pass messages back to the UI thread.

HandlerThread basically does exactly what's above.  It encapsulates the weird calls you need to do to make a looper, but it makes you use some odd looking code to make the actual handler for that thread.  Nothing wrong with using it, but it won't save you much effort.

Comment: "processing a message takes a significant amount of time" - all the amount of time of working on the thread is done outside the handler, I use handler only to send message to `Looper`, so what can takes a lot of time? the UI updating from the thread?

Comment: No, this is a reason why someone would want to use a handler on a separate thread-  if the specific message that they're processing requires a lot of time in their implementation.  It's not a general thing with all handlers.

Comment: I still cant get it, what is the benefit of creating a messages queue for thread, its going to do a long job in any case without using `main Thread`. is it better sending messages to one thread so he run them other then starting each time a new `Thread`? is it the big different?

Comment: The advantage of using a thread for the message queue, or of using a message queue?  The advantage of using a thread for it is to allow the UI to still run on its own thread, so it doesn't become unresponsive.  The advantage of using a message queue is to handle events in the order received and to avoid multithreading and synchronization issues.